# Does a computer assembled only from CE marked subassemblies still need CE testing?

Tags: fcc, certification, compliance

The FCC (bulletin 62) mentions an exception allowing someone to assemble and sell computers without the normal FCC testing requirement "as long as they start with an FCC-authorized system and add to it only FCC-authorized peripherals..."

Do the CE mark requirements have a similar exception?

(It is completely understood, by the way, that any answers are expressions of opinion, not legal advice)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the completed system needs independent testing and labeling to be sold in the European Union. I'm not an agency expert but all the products I've been associated with had to be tested with all the components connected that would be in the final system.

The CE mark certifies the system meets a variety of requirements, not the least of which is electrical safety.  If you take five components that all have a CE mark but just barely, the sum of the five may push the system outside of limits. Let's say that the components all have 50uA leakage levels and all pass.  The assembled system might have something like 150uA to 250uA leakage and over the 100uA limit.

The same for RF emissions levels, dielectric breakdown, etc.

The good news is that with CE marks components, you know that they were safety tested and passed and chances are good that the system will, as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

FCC and CE are different things. I would say, yes you need additonal CE proof for the assembled devcie, because you can use CE certified devices and you don't use regulations when you put all together. But I also think that you need CE test for series product, if you assemble one piece then it is up to you to write a declaration where you take the responsability that the device meets CE standard.
For example a machine bulider writes the declaration, then if there is an injury the inspector looks if the machine is built accordingly, if not, they go for hunt on the producer. If you buy a chinese machine with CE and you cut your fingers, then the lawyers from China say that they will not charge anybody in China and you can forget about your finger, and that a CE means China Export